# What does "CPU 1 - Parked" mean in the Windows Resource Monitor?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, resource-monitor

While poking around in Resource Monitor, I saw that two of my CPUs, CPU 1 and 3, are marked as "parked", like so:

[image: screenshot showing CPUs 1 and 3 are parked]

What exactly does this mean? I'm running Windows 7 x64 on a Core i3-530.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows automatically disables or [*parks* cores to save energy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/10/03/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-core-parking-intelligent-timer-tick-timer-coalescing.aspx) in laptops. Even with the Power Plan set to full performance, CPU cores are parked by Windows.

You can disable it for better performance and poorer battery life. Instructions [here](http://forums.techarena.in/guides-tutorials/1362124.htm) and [here](http://engrjpo.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/disable-cpu-core-parking/). (Be careful, editing the registry is dangerous)

Comment: But I can see "CPU 3 Parked" in a desktop machine, which is not a laptop though.

Comment: Same here, I'm on a desktop, lot of parking going on.

Comment: I clicked the link but it no longer takes me to a page about parking.